# how to abort wget?

Tags: wget

sometime when I use wget to recursively download a website, I made a mistake and want abortion.

I've Searched over and over and no luck

Answer (score 35):

What shell are you running `wget` from?  In many shells, CTRL+C will cancel the currently-running process.  If you are running a Linux shell, `pkill -9 wget` should be able to force-kill it if it's running in the background.

Answer (score 8):

send a interuption signal.

- In the same console you can do Ctrl+C
- In other console than the one you are using: `pkill -9 wget`

Answer (score 1):

If it's because its hungup in retries on an unresponsive server, you can try to send it the signal SIGQUIT (-3) (tested on Wget 1.16).

`$> kill -SIGQUIT <wget pid>`